# Get value of structure inside a structure array

Tags: c

```
typedef struct{
  int number;
  char name[100];
} Apple

typedef struct{
  Apple *apple;
  int bit[2];
} AppleArray;

int main(){
  AppleArray *aArray;
  loadApple(&aArray);
}

loadApple(AppleArray **aArray){
  *aArray = NULL;
  for(i=0; i<100; i++){
    *aArray = realloc(*aArray, (i+1) * sizeof(AppleArray));

    /*SEGFAULT here*/
    aArray[i]->apple = NULL;

    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
      aArray[i]->apple = realloc(aArray[i]->apple, sizeof(Apple) * (j+1))
    }
  }

}
```

I want to have an AppleArray with specific size. Each AppleArray will have two Apple. However, I get segfault when i assign NULL to aArray[i]->apple. What is the problem there?

**EDIT :**

```
loadApple(AppleArray **aArray){
  *aArray = malloc(100 * sizeof(AppleArray));
  for(i=0; i<100; i++){

    /*SEGFAULT here*/
    aArray[i]->apple = NULL;

    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
      aArray[i]->apple = realloc(aArray[i]->apple, sizeof(Apple) * (j+1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be *aArray[i]. Pls check my answer.

Comment: @Jay error: incompatible types in assignment in line *aArray[0]->apple = NULL;

Comment: Try (*aArray)[0].apple = NULL;

Answer (score 1):

You can call `realloc()` only on an address that was returned to you by an prior memory allocation function like `malloc()`or `calloc()` otherwise it gives you **Undefined Behavior**.

**C99 Standard 7.20.3.4-3: The realloc function:**

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, **if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or
>   realloc function, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: i already set *aArray = NULL.
But i can't set aArray[i]->apple to NULL.

Comment: Setting *aArray to NULL is unnecessary anyways, provided you use **malloc** to allocate memory instead of realloc...

Comment: Edited to use malloc. It's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Als has mentioned above, you are also having an array out-of-bounds read problem as after your loop, i value will be 100 and you are trying to access `aArray[100]` whereas in your logic (though incorrect) your would have allocated memory only till `aArray[99]`.

Your loadApple function  can be rewritten as below:

```
loadApple(AppleArray **aArray)
{   
   *aArray = NULL;   
   *aArray = malloc(100 * sizeof(AppleArray));

   //I have shown index as 0 here just as an example.
   (*aArray)[0].apple = NULL;      
   (*aArray)[0].apple = malloc(2 * sizeof(Apple));

}
```

This code should also give the same behavior which the logic of your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mahmoud, Thanks for editing my answer. I am not getting the options to mark code etc or make a word bold etc. Does anyone know why my browser (IE) is not displaying those? Before it used to be displayed.

Comment: error: incompatible types in assignment in line *aArray[0]->apple = NULL;

Comment: @Jay No prob. I notice updates are rolled to the sites often during the night. Perhaps a transient bug - I'm on Chrome.

Comment: I'd suggest `aArray[0]->apple` but I guess that's a matter of taste

Comment: @Yefim Dinitz, Would aArray[0]->apple work? As I understand, *aArray only is pointer to AppleArray and holds dynamically allocated memory. But, aArray is just a place holder for *aArray and should mostly be in stack. So, aArray[i] will try to access successive locations in stack eventually leading to undefined behavior. Pls correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define MAX_SIZE 5
#define NAME_SIZE 100
#define APPLE_NUM 2

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
}Apple;

typedef struct
{
    Apple* apple;
    int bit[2];
}AppleArray;

void printApple(AppleArray** aArray)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%4d: bit[0] = %d, bit[1] = %d\n", i, (*aArray + i)->bit[0], (*aArray + i)->bit[1]);

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < APPLE_NUM; ++j)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\tapple[%d]: number = %d, name = %s\n", 
                    j, 
                    (*aArray + i)->apple[j].number, 
                    (*aArray + i)->apple[j].name);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void loadApple(AppleArray **aArray)
{
    *aArray = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        AppleArray* tmp = (AppleArray*)realloc(*aArray, (i+1) * sizeof(AppleArray));
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            *aArray = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            //error
            free(*aArray);
            *aArray = NULL;
            exit(0);
        }

        /*SEGFAULT here*/
        //aArray[i]->apple = NULL;
        (*aArray + i)->apple = NULL;
        (*aArray + i)->bit[0] = i;
        (*aArray + i)->bit[1] = i + 1;

        /*
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            (*aArray + i)->apple = realloc(aArray[i]->apple, sizeof(Apple) * (j+1));
        }
        */

        (*aArray + i)->apple = (Apple*)realloc(NULL, sizeof(Apple) * APPLE_NUM);

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < APPLE_NUM; ++j)
        {
            (*aArray + i)->apple[j].number = j;
            snprintf( (*aArray + i)->apple[j].name, NAME_SIZE, "apple_%d_%d", i, j);
        }
  }//for
}

void destroyApple(AppleArray* thiz)
{
    if (thiz == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        free(thiz[i].apple);
        thiz[i].apple = NULL;
    }

    free(thiz);
}

int main()
{
    AppleArray *aArray;
    loadApple(&aArray);
    printApple(&aArray);
    destroyApple(aArray);

    return 0;
}
```